# I need to have an anchor navigate to the page, and that page ONLY display specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am curious to know if there is a way to specifically display certain elements based off the referring link. I have dropdown nav bar with multiple  links, and I need these links need to go to the linked page, but only display elements with a certain class name.

For example:

```
<br>
```

Click the 'Entertainment' drop-down selection of the 'Work' nav-link. It navigates to the desired page, BUT, only displays elements with a class of '.entr'. Similar with the 'Film' drop-down selection of the 'Work' nav; navigate but only display elements with a class of '.film'.

I can do it on the 'Work' page with a different set of links devoted solely to this purpose, but I want to know if its possible to do anything like this with the navigation bar links from a different page than the elements are on.

Comment: All that and you "example" is `<br>`? Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah that isn't what was originally asked. That was something I didn't know happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you're using something like this for your Navigation links: 
`<a href='/work#Entertainment>Entertainment</a>`

You could set all of the elements on your page to be hidden `display:none` and then do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() { 
  const hash = document.location.hash;
  let className;
  let elementsToShow;

  switch (hash) {
    case 'Entertainment' :
        className ='.entr';
        break;
    case 'Film' :
        className ='.film';
        break;
    case 'News' :
        className = '.news';
        break;
  }

  if (className) {
    elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll(className);
  } else {
    elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.class-on-all-elements');
  }

  elementsToShow.forEach( function(element){
    element.style.display = 'block';
  }); 
}
```

Walking through the whole process...

Clicking on `<a href='/work#Entertainment>Entertainment</a>` takes you to the page with the url `website.com/work#Entertainment`

On that page the script runs when that page loads: `window.onload = function() {`

It gets the "hash" (everything after the `#`) and saves it to the variable `hash`:
`const hash = document.location.hash;`

It then compares the value of `hash` to a number of different cases: `switch (hash) {`

If it finds a match it then assigns the correct class name to the variable `className`:

`case 'Film' :
  className ='.film';`

If it has a value for `className`, it selects all the elements with that class (`elements = document.querySelectorAll(className)`) and adds them to the variable `elementsToShow`. If there is no value for `className` it adds all the elements to `elementsToShow` since we don't want a blank page.

Finally, and loops through all the elements in `elementsToShow` and sets them to be visible: `element.style.display = 'block'`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that defaulting to having your content start out hidden by default isn't probably a great idea, and you could a version of this that goes through and hides all the elements _except_ those with a matching `className`, but it would depend pretty heavily on the structure of your markup and isn't really something I could come up without first seeing that.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed @Brice. Thank you very much!